# ASP.net:ext.net gridpanel filter date doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ext.net, gridpanel

Look this code

```
                <Model>
                    <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server" IDProperty="DownTimeSequenceNo">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:ModelField Name="RowNumber" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="DownTimeSequenceNo" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Status" Type="String"  />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Keterangan"  />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="DownTimeDate" Type="Date" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="WSID" Type="String" />
                             </Fields>
                    </ext:Model>
                </Model>
                <Sorters>
                    <ext:DataSorter Property="DownTimeSequenceNo" Direction="ASC" />
                </Sorters>
            </ext:Store>
        </Store>
        <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column ID="Column1" runat="server" Text="No" DataIndex="RowNumber" Sortable="False"
                    Width="50" Filterable="false" />
                <ext:Column ID="Column2" runat="server" Text="DownTimeSequenceNo" DataIndex="DownTimeSequenceNo"
                    Visible="false" />
                <ext:Column ID="Column3" runat="server" Text="Status" DataIndex="Status" Width="50" />
                <ext:Column ID="Column4" runat="server" Text="Keterangan" DataIndex="Keterangan"
                    Width="100" Filterable="false" Sortable="False" />
                <ext:DateColumn ID="Column5" runat="server" Text="Tanggal" DataIndex="DownTimeDate"
                    Width="80" Format="dd/MMM/Y HH:mm" Filterable="true" />
                <ext:Column ID="Column6" runat="server" Text="WSID" DataIndex="WSID" Width="50" />
            </Columns>
        </ColumnModel>
        <SelectionModel>
            <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel ID="CheckboxSelectionModel1" runat="server" Mode="Multi" />
        </SelectionModel>
        <Plugins>
            <ext:FilterHeader ID="FilterHeader1" runat="server" Remote="true"   />
        </Plugins>
    </ext:GridPanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

This code works filtering if the filter data type is string, but it doesn't work when it is date. What should i do ?
I have tried to google and ext-net examples doesn't provide any help.

Comment: I can investigate if you provide a standalone runnable test case.

Answer (score 0):

take alook at this offical example

[here](http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Plugins/GridFilters_Remote/)

u need to declare feature and specify date here

```
<Features>
                        <ext:GridFilters ID="GridFilters1" runat="server">
                            <Filters>
                                <ext:NumericFilter DataIndex="Id" />
                                <ext:StringFilter DataIndex="Company" />
                                <ext:NumericFilter DataIndex="Price" />
                                <ext:DateFilter DataIndex="Date">
                                    <DatePickerOptions runat="server" TodayText="Now" />
                                </ext:DateFilter>
                                <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Size" Options="extra small,small,medium,large,extra large" />
                                <ext:BooleanFilter DataIndex="Visible" />
                            </Filters>
                        </ext:GridFilters>
                    </Features>
```

Comment: @user41935 uses an alternative approach - FilterHeader.